# How do I get BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE to display on the screen?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-unit-test-framework

I'm fumbling my way through the Boost Unit Testing Framework and have set up a basic functioning unit test. I'm using `BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE` to let the user know which tests are running, but the messages don't display on the screen. For example:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest

#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(MyTestSuite, MyTestFixture)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MessageTest)
{
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( "no one sees this!" );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

I have tried defining `BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL` to `all` but this has no effect. I got that idea from the [Boost log-level parameter page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/utf/parameters/log_level.html), but I think the concept of the *log* might not be related to what is actually displayed on the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `<program-name> --log_level=message`?

Comment: putenv("BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL=message") in main(), works too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE.html):

> Messages generated by this tool do not appear in test log output with default value of the active log level threshold. For these messages to appear the active log level threshold has to be set to a value below or equal to "message".

Either set the environment variable `BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL` to `message` when running your test binary:

```
BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL=message <your_test>
```

or pass the command line argument `--log_level`:

```
<your_test> --log_level=message
```

Comment: Where to put this code? I put it in the test case `BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL = message <testcase1>`, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Zhang as mentioned, you need to export this as an *environment variable* in your terminal.