# Get boost unit-test output in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, boost

I'm running boost unit-tests of a c++ project in eclipse (Version:2019-06), and would like to print some output.

cout does not print to the console during testing and boost own BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE doesnt output anything either.
According to boost documentation (see answer to this question: [How do I get BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE to display on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19472909/1085370)) I should set log_level to 'message'.

When I add `--log_level=message` to 'Program Arguments' in Run Configurations I get the following message:

```
Test setup error: Fail to process runtime parameters: Unexpected repetition of the parameter log_level in the following position:
```

When i add the BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL and/or log_level variables in the 'Environment' tab of Run Configurations, nothing happens.

What is the correct place to specify log-level for boost unit tests? 
Is there any other way to get output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test messages, written using `BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("...");` will appear in eclipses own test output window if the message button, labelled **i** (see image) is toggled.

One caveat, this only happens when Boost test output is valid xml. If for example the code under test writes to `cout` it will break the xml and no output will be visible in eclipse, except a warning about malformed xml.

[image]